# How do I Intent from non-mainActivity class to other non-mainActivity class?

Tags: android, android-intent

Just like the title. I'm trying to move activity from non-mainActivity class to the other non-mainActivity class. I heard that moving like that would require something in the manifest, but I don't know what to do. Please help me out!

Comment: Have you checked https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity?

Comment: @HendraWD      But that's moving from MainActivity. I heard that moving from other class would be a bit different than that.

Comment: Actually the same, but you should specify the activity class

Comment: @HendraWD      Thanks!